# Empty Variable when inside the <select> markup

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, scope

just to know if someone have any idea why this bug is happening.

I have the following code

```
<?php 
foreach($productArray as $key=>$value)
{
    if ($key == 'cod_prod')
    {
?>
      <td>
```

}
    }
    ?>

I didnt finished the rest of the code because its working fine, except by this part.

In the example above if I put the var_dump($codeList) in the first position it prints out the results of the array just fine, if i place the var_dump($codeList) in the second position it comes back empty. If i put both the var_dumps in both positions the same thing happens

To check this im using **var_dump($codeList)**, took out the options and everything else and the array simply come back EMPTY if I insert the **select** markup

Any ideas?

UPDATE

The $codeList is being generated at a controller, in this case, here

```
    $this->setVar(array(
        'DataAtual' => $Solicitacao->DataAtual,
        'ClienteEmail' => $Solicitacao->clientEmail,
        'ClienteNome' => $Solicitacao->userName,
        'ClienteTelefone' => $Solicitacao->userTelefone,
        'VendedorNome' => $Solicitacao->VendedorNome,
        'VendedorEmail' => $Solicitacao->VendedorEmail,
        'VendedorTelefone' => $Solicitacao->VendedorTelefone,
        'PagamentoForma' => $Solicitacao->PagamentoForma,
        'PagamentoPrazo' => $Solicitacao->PagamentoPrazo,
        'PagamentoFrete' => $Solicitacao->PagamentoFrete,
        'Produtos' => $Solicitacao->ProdutosArr,
        'Observacoes' => $Solicitacao->ObservacoesArr,
        'MensagemEmail' => $Solicitacao->MensagemEmail,
        'PageTitle' => $Solicitacao->PageTitle,
        'Action' => $Solicitacao->Acao,
        'PageType' => $Solicitacao->PageType,
        'vendorInfo' => $Solicitacao->vendorInfo,
        **'codeList' => $Solicitacao->codeList,**
        'moneyFields' => $Solicitacao->moneyFields,
        'coresArr' => $Solicitacao->coresArr
        ));
```

The $Solicitacao->codeList is being generated in the Model, here (just a simple array made by wordpress)

```
 $getCodesListSQL = "SELECT cod_prod FROM wp_products ORDER BY cod_prod ASC;";
        $this->codeList = $wpdb->get_results($getCodesListSQL);
```

**RESUME**

A FULL array Gets dumped

```
 var_dump($codeList);
    echo '<select>';
    //var_dump($codeList);
```

A EMPTY array Gets dumped

```
 //var_dump($codeList);
    echo '<select>';
    var_dump($codeList);
```

Comment: How does the generated html code look like?

Comment: Do you look at the resulting page or at its source? When you look at the page: Are you aware that select requires its content to be <option> to be displayed properly?

Comment: Where does `$codeList` come from?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you print the values of `$codeList`. Can you show more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is not visible because it is in a SELECT element. SELECT only accepts OPTION elements as children. Do a View Source on the generated HTML and see that the values are actually there, just that browsers don't know what to do with them.

It depends on the browser but: when you view the generated HTML , if it is shown in a view where you can collapse nodes then it gets the HTML by calling innerHTML function on the shown element. If the inner HTML is not valid then it shows nothing.

The content is there but the browser chooses to ignore and remove it in the view you are using to view the generated HTML.

Comment: Nope, im dumping the var results to see whats inside it, its like if by putting the <select> its emptying the var $codeList for some reason

Comment: It depends on the browser but: when you view the generated HTML , if it is shown in a view where you can collapse nodes the it gets the HTML by calling innerHTML function on the shown element. If the inner HTML is not valid then it shows nothing.

Comment: Yep thats correct, just checked on the source and they are all there. Im currently debugging with chrome, maybe its time to go bacck to firefox for debugging?

Comment: Were you using Inspect Element or View page source?

Comment: I tryed with Inspect Element first but nothing were shown, i was able to find it in the View Page Source however

Comment: Inspect Element shows what is in the DOM, and your content did not make it to DOM because it was not valid where it was placed.

Comment: But you know whats the worst part? If I try to iterate a loop inside the select to dynamically generate the options for that select it also comes empty, the only way to do that is by creating the entire select and its options inside an PHP var and the echoing that var. So, here I go creating html in the CONTROLLER and ruining the use of the VIEW

Comment: @OvidiuPacurar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1852/discussion-between-fabio-and-ovidiu-pacurar)

Answer (score 0):

Does this give the results you want?

```
 <?php 
        foreach($productArray as $key=>$value)
        {
            if ($key == 'cod_prod')
            {
              echo '<td>';
              echo '<select>';                                            

                 foreach($codeList as $codigo)
                 {
                    //DO STUFF
                 }

              echo '</select>';
              echo '</td>';     
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Nope, it happens the exactly same thing, odd huh?